# Необходимо перебрать 2 массива одновременно через @foreach

Tags: php, laravel

Вообщем контроллер отправляет 2 массива во вьюху

```
     class Admin_controller extends Controller
{
public function monitoring_user()
{
         $data=[
         'users'=> User::join('user_info', 'users.id', '=', 'user_id')->get(),
            'role' => Role::join('users_roles','roles.id','=','role_id')->get()
            ];
return view('monitoring_user' ,$data);
```

а во вьюхи необходим  обработать в одной итерации 2 массива

```
      @if (count($users))
                            @foreach($users as $user)
                                    <tr>
                     <td><center>{!! $user->login !!}</center></td> 
                       <td><center>{!! $user->name !!}</center></td>
                       <td><center>{!! $user->surname !!}</center></td>
                     <td><center>{!! $user->patronymicname !!}</center></td> 
///  <td><center>{!! $role->name !!}</center> <td>
     @endforeach
```

пользователей нормально перебираю но также необходимо и роли тут же вывести
Извиняюсь за кривое объяснение и за свою безграмотность

Comment: Ну и делайте вложенный `@foreach`

Comment: Вложенный нельзя так как, это строка таблицы единая,  если сделаю вложенный он выведет все роли, а мне нужно по одной @u_mulder

Comment: Так вам и не надо все, вам надо каждый элемент вложенного форыча сначала проверить - его юзер_ид равен текущему? Если да - выведите данные текущего элемента, если нет - смотрим в следующий.

Comment: О спасибо большое, что то я протупил  @u_mulder

Comment: Я конечно не знаю как там у вас модели устроены, но может можно эти две сущност как-то поджойнить чтобы с юзером сразу его роли выпадали? Тогда вы обойдетесь одним форычем.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую ещё раз соединить, просто там 4 таблицы, поэтому были проблемы, как бы соединял но ничего не возвращал данные из бд @u_mulder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно построить запрос с использованием `JOIN` оператора и тогда не нужно соединять эти массивы и что-то выдумывать с переборкой одновременно данных, так как этого в php нельзя сделать!

```
SELECT Persons.LastName, Persons.FirstName, Orders.OrderNo
FROM Persons
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Persons.P_Id=Orders.P_Id
ORDER BY Persons.LastName
```

[Вот ссылка на русскую документацию](http://dimonchik.com/sql-left-join.html)